# Accessing a variable of a thread from another thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, setter, decrement

I'm trying to access and modify a variable of a thread in another thread in java, and I really don't know how to do this.

ex :

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    int value = 10;
    public void run() {
        // random stuff
    }
}
Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
        // of course the bellow line will not work
        r1.value--; // I want here to be able to decrement the variable "value" of r1
    }
}
Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Is there any way to create a getter and setter for a thread in java?

*Edit:* the answers were good, but I was not clear in my question, I will try asking a better question

Comment: Threads don't have variables. Classes have members, and methods have parameters and local variables. If you re-analyze your problem along those lines the answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make it sort of work but, I suggest you use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) which is shared between threads.

```
final AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(10);
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // random stuff using value
    }
}
Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
        value.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

You can use AtomicReference for references to objects.

Answer (score 8):

Create a runnable, and use the setters and getters you define in said runnable.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    private volatile String myString;
    public String setString(String value){this.myString = value;}
    public String getString(){
        return myString;
    }
    public void run(){}
}
```

Note `volatile` keyword is used here. The volatile keyword ensures if this String changes in one thread, that all threads will see the change.  If instead I ensure that the only access to the String object is through synchronized context, then the volatile keyword would not be necessary.

To demonstrate my point, the above code and the below code are both thread-safe but are different as no 2 threads can enter `setString` and `getString` simultaneously in the example below.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    private String myString;
    public synchronized String setString(String value){this.myString = value;}
    public synchronized String getString(){
        return myString;
    }
    public void run(){}
}
```

A thread is really just executing a runnable.  You could use this like so:

```
MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable();
Thread myThread = new Thread(runnable);
myThread.start();
String myString = runnable.getString();
```

Using atomic values for primitives is fine, but if you ever want to share a more complex object, you'll have to read about [threading and synchronization.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

For example:

```
public class Stats{
    int iterations;
    long runtime;
    public Stats(){
        iterations = 0;
        runtime=0;
    }
    public synchronized void setIterations(int value){this.iterations = value;}
    public synchronized void setRuntime(long milliseconds){
        this.runtime = milliseconds;
    }
    public synchronized int getIterations(){
         return iterations;
    }
    public synchronized long getRuntime(){return runtime;}
}

public class StatRunnable implements Runnable{
    Stats stats;
    boolean active;
    public StatRunnable(){
        this.active=true;
    }
    public Stats getStats(){
        return stats;
    }
    long calculateRuntime(){return 0L;}
    public void run(){
        while(active){
            //i'm synchronizing with stats to ensure no other thread alters values
            //simultaneously.
            synchronized(stats){
                stats.setIterations(stats.getIterations()+1);
                stats.setRuntime(calculateRuntime());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code shows an example of synchronization with non-primitive objects via the `synchronized` keyword.  Using the synchronized keyword in a method definition locks the class using itself as the synchronizing object.

A final note, the synchronized keyword isn't just used in method definitions. You can use it to synchronize on instances within methods as I've done in the `run` method in `StatRunnable`.

Comment: Can you provide an example in a thread safe way?  This looks like the original code, but with setter/getters as well as direct access to the field.

Comment: This is thread safe as nothing touches the String :) but yes I'll write a more complex example.

Comment: AFAIK you have replaced `String myString = runnable.myString;` with `String myString = runnable.getString();` which does the same thing.

Comment: I know, better a couple years late than never, but your solution worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @kpont glad to hear it!  Hopefully it helped you with threading, its a complex subject.